# Remove empty tags using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to delete empty tags such as `<label></label>`, `<font> </font>` so that:

```
<label></label><form></form>
<p>This is <span style="color: red;">red</span> 
<i>italic</i>
</p>
```

will be cleaned as:

```
<p>This is <span style="color: red;">red</span> 
<i>italic</i>
</p>
```

I have this RegEx in javascript, but it deletes the the empty tags but it also delete this: `"<i>italic</i></p>"`

```
str=str.replace(/<[\S]+><\/[\S]+>/gim, "");
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I think stack overflow's markup may be messing with you. The before and after of your cleanup routine result look the same to us.

Comment: The two lines appear the same. Can you use the code block so the text doesn't get formatted?

Comment: Fixed up the markup, bods, hope that makes more sense.

Comment: This forum is that fast? I can't believe you guys are that quick!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have "not spaces" as your character class, which means "`<i>italic</i></p>`" will match. The first half of your regex will match "`<(i>italic</i)>`" and the second half "`</(p)>`". (I've used brackets to show what each `[\S]+` matches.)

Change this:

```
/<[\S]+><\/[\S]+>/
```

To this:

```
/<[^/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>/
```

Overall you should really be using a proper HTML processor, but if you're munging HTML soup this should suffice :)

Comment: This is the closest expression. Others don't work.
But this one delete </i></p> as well.

I am playing with the code. Thanks

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: It won't really make a difference unless you're parsing some *very* messed up HTML.

Comment: These all fail in case of something like "<blockquote data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/"></blockquote>".

So I prefer this regex: <([^\/>]+|[^\/>]*["\'][^"\'>]*["\'][^\/>]+)>\s*<\/[^>]+>

Answer (score 23):

Regex is not for HTML. If you're in JavaScript anyway I'd be encouraged to use jQuery DOM processing.

Something like:

```
$('*:empty').remove();
```

Alternatively:

```
$("*").filter(function() 
{ 
     return $.trim($(this).html()).length > 0; 
}).remove();
```

Comment: I have other regex cleaning in the same function. I prefer this way unfortunately.

The content is within an IFrame where user paste from word doc.
I am cleaning all MSFT junks

Comment: I will look into JQuery option.

Comment: I agree that regex *seems* easier, but if you're already in javascript jQuery is so much easier and makes it so much easier to extend capabilities as well (what if requirements ask you to start removing nested <p> tags, or tags that are nested more than 3 levels deep?)

Comment: I am using jquery. I haven't done this type of cleaning before using jquery.

Any simple example will help.. Thanks

Comment: The example provided doesn't work? Let me know what kind of example you need and I'm happy to help.

Comment: I know the formatting won't work out in a comment, but copy and paste this snipped to the head of your document: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('*:empty').remove(); }); </script>` What it does it that it waits for the document to be ready and then it removes the empty tags (as per Graphain's example). Make sure to load the jQuery library first, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ are pretty helpful, but let me know what you need in particular.

Comment: Thanks Graphain.
The above html is the stored in a string variablein js.
I am doing regex on that variable.
I already ran another set of regex to do to the other cleaning.

I can drop that html inside a div and process using jquery?

Comment: @Graphain Thanks. I hope it will help bobby getting started. Your code worked fine.

Comment: @Bobby: Yep, pretty sure you can go $(data).('*:empty'), where data is your string var. Let me know if that works.

Comment: P.S. For future reference, at the time of this comment stream `Graphain` was my username.

Comment: This will give `false` -> `$('<x>  </x>').is(':empty')`

Answer (score 9):

All the answers with regex are only validate

```
<label></label>
```

but in the case of

```
<label> </label>
<label>    </label>
<label>
</label>
```

try this pattern to get all the above

```
<[^/>]+>[ \n\r\t]*</[^>]+>
```

Comment: Its also taking account if I have 'ul' followed by 'li'. How would I skip that?

Comment: I suggest replacing `[\n\r\t]*` with `[\s]*` which would mean the same thing plus a couple more (\f and \v) and space too..

Answer (score 3):

You need `/<[\S]+?><\/[\S]+?>/` -- the difference is the `?`s after the `+`s, to match "as few as possible" (AKA "non-greedy match") nonspace characters (though 1 or more), instead of the bare `+`s which match"as many as possible" (AKA "greedy match").

Avoiding regular expressions altogether, as the other answer recommends, is also an excellent idea, but I wanted to point out the important greedy vs non-greedy distinction, which will serve you well in a huge variety of situations where regexes *are* warranted.

Answer (score 2):

I like MattMitchell's jQuery solution but here is another option using native JavaScript.

```
function CleanChildren(elem)
{
    var children = elem.childNodes;
    var len = elem.childNodes.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var child = children[i];

        if(child.hasChildNodes())
            CleanChildren(child);
        else
            elem.removeChildNode(child);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modern native JavaScript solution; which is actually quite similar to the jQuery one from 2010. I adapted it from that answer for a project that I am working on, and thought I would share it here.

```
document.querySelectorAll("*:empty").forEach((x)=>{x.remove()});
```

- `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`; which is essentially an array of all DOM nodes which match the CSS selector given to it as an argument.

  - `*:empty` is a selector which selects all elements (`*` means "any element") that is empty (which is what `:empty` means).

    This will select any empty element within the *entire document*, if you only wanted to remove any empty elements from within a certain part of the page (i.e. only those within some `div` element); you can add an id to that element and then use the selector `#id *:empty`, which means any empty element within the element with an id of `id`.

    **This is almost certainly what you want.** Technically some important tags (e.g. `<meta>` tags, `<br>` tags, `<img>` tags, etc) are "empty"; so without specifying a scope, you will end up deleting some tags you probably care about.
- `forEach` loops through every element in the resulting `NodeList`, and runs the anonymous function `(x)=>{x.remove()}` on it. `x` is the current element in the list, and calling `.remove()` on it removes that element from the DOM.

Hopefully this helps someone. It's amazing to see how far JavaScript has come in just 8 years; from almost always needing a library to write something complex like this in a concise manner to being able to do so natively.

## Edit

So, the method detailed above will work fine in most circumstances, but it has two issues:

- Elements like `<div> </div>` are not treated as `:empty` (not the space in-between). CSS Level 4 selectors fix this with the introduction of the `:blank` selector (which is like empty except it ignores whitespace), but currently only Firefox supports it (in vendor-prefixed form).
- Self-closing tags are caught by `:empty` - and this will remain the case with `:blank`, too.

I have written a slightly larger function which deals with these two use cases:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((x)=>{
    let tagName = "</" + x.tagName + ">";
    if (x.outerHTML.slice(tagName.length).toUpperCase() == tagName
        && /[^\s]/.test(x.innerHTML)) {
        x.remove();
    }
});
```

We iterate through every element on the page. We grab that element's tag name (for example, if the element is a div this would be `DIV`, and use it to construct a closing tag - e.g. `</DIV>`.

That tag is 6 characters long. We check if the upper-cased last 6 characters of the elements HTML matches that. If it does we continue. If it doesn't, the element does't have a closing tag, and therefore must be self-closing. This is preferable over a list, because it means you don't have to update anything should a new self-closing tag get added to the spec.

Then, we check if the contents of the element contain any whitespace. `/[^\s]/` is a RegEx. `[]` is a set in RegEx, and will match any character that appears inside it. If `^` is the first element, the set becomes *negated* - it will match any element that is NOT in the set. `\s` means whitespace - tabs, spaces, line breaks. So what `[^\s]` says is "any character that is not white space".

Matching against that, if the tag is not self-closing, and its contents contain a non-whitespace character, then we remove it.

---

Of course, this is a bit bigger and less elegant than the previous one-liner. But it should work for essentially every case.

Comment: I discovered that this code actually removes the also needed unclosed tags like link and meta. This actually is a nice 'one-liner' but its a little rough on the html. Trying to find an adjustment that fixes this though. Plus one for simplicity definately.

Comment: @Le-Nerdtm I've added an edit to my post, which should solve those issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
<([^>]+)\s*>\s*<\/\1\s*>
```

```
<div>asdf</div>
<div></div> -- will match only this
<div></notdiv>
-- and this
<div  >  
    </div   >
```

try yourself https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of greedy regex. Try this:

`str=str.replace(/<[\^>]+><\/[\S]+>/gim, "");`

or

`str=str.replace(/<[\S]+?><\/[\S]+>/gim, "");`

In your regex, `<[\S]+?>` matches `<i>italic</i>` and the `<\/[\S]+>` matches the `</p>`

Comment: I see what is missing..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one 
`text = text.replace(/<[^/>][^>]>\s</[^>]+>/gim, "");`

Answer (score 0):

found this on code pen:
jQuery though but does the job

```
$('element').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === '') {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

You will need to alter the element to point to where you want to remove empty tags. Do not point at document cause it will result in my answer at Toastrackenigma

Answer (score 0):

remove empty tags with cheerio will and also removing images:

```
  $('*')
    .filter(function(index, el) {
      return (
        $(el)
          .text()
          .trim().length === 0
      )
    })
    .remove()
```

remove empty tags with cheerio, but also keep images:

```
  $('*')
    .filter(function(index, el) {
      return (
        el.tagName !== 'img' &&
        $(el).find(`img`).length === 0 &&
        $(el)
          .text()
          .trim().length === 0
      )
    })
    .remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

if just want to remove all empty tags

```
  html = html.replace(/<([A-z]+)([^>^/]*)>\s*<\/\1>/gim, '');
```

but carefull, sometimes, table will wrong display. So if you want to  remove empty html tags except  and  in javascript, we use callback

```
html = html.replace(/<([A-z]+)([^>^/]*)>\s*<\/\1>/gim, function(match, p1, p2) {
  if (p1 === 'tr' || p1 === 'td') {
    return match;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
});
```