# How to remove element if self closing tag is found

Tags: c#

I am pulling an xml file from third party app which looks like this

```
<round round_id="14208" name="5th Round" start_date="2013-09-06" end_date="2013-09-10" type="cup" groups="0" has_outgroup_matches="no" last_updated="2011-04-05 14:15:02">
    --Some Data with more elements
</round>

<round round_id="14208" name="5th Round" start_date="2013-09-06" end_date="2013-09-10" type="cup" groups="0" has_outgroup_matches="no" last_updated="2011-04-05 14:15:02">
    --Some Data with more elements
</round>
```

My problem is some time this tag comes with self closing tag like this

```
<round round_id="14208" name="5th Round" start_date="2013-09-06" end_date="2013-09-10" type="cup" groups="0" has_outgroup_matches="no" last_updated="2011-04-05 14:15:02"/>
```

I want to check for self closing tags and remove the element.

Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look and XMLDocument and its child nodes property. I don't know it well enough to post any code unfortunately

Comment: Take a look here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318408/remove-empty-xml-tag

Comment: This is wrong XML so no way parse it as XML, I believe you parse this file as plain text, so how you search for `</remove>` closing tag? Search for `/>` in the same way

Comment: Sorry I posted with wrong closing tags.Now Corrected
Added </round> closing tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var file = "C:\\YourPath\\data.xml";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/rounds/round");
foreach (XmlNode item in nodes)
{
    if (item.InnerXml == String.Empty)
    {
        item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item);
    }
}
doc.Save(file);
```