# Create an XML file from another XML file with tags that are not empty

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file as you can see below.  I want to create another XML file using this XML file but the new XML file can only have those tags which have values.  For example - in the below XML file I have an employee Sam who does not have city and state so my new XML file must not contain these empty tags.  I am new to LINQ to XML but my friend said that I can achieve it using LINQ to XML. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <Employees>
         <Employee>
<EmpId>1</EmpId>
<Name>Sam</Name>   
<Sex>Male</Sex>
<Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
          <Address>
  <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
  <City></City>
  <State></State>
  <Zip>95220</Zip>
  <Country>USA</Country>
</Address>
      </Employee>
             <Employee>
<EmpId>2</EmpId>
<Name>Lucy</Name>
<Sex>Female</Sex>
<Phone Type="Home">143-555-0763</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">434-555-0567</Phone>
<Address>
  <Street>Jess Bay</Street>
  <City>Alta</City>
  <State>CA</State>
  <Zip>95701</Zip>
  <Country>USA</Country>
</Address>
  </Employee>
       <Employee>
<EmpId>3</EmpId>
<Name>Kate</Name>
<Sex>Female</Sex>
<Phone Type="Home">166-555-0231</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">233-555-0442</Phone>
<Address>
  <Street>23 Boxen Street</Street>
  <City>Milford</City>
  <State>CA</State>
  <Zip>96121</Zip>
  <Country>USA</Country>
</Address>
     </Employee>
           <Employee>
<EmpId>4</EmpId>
<Name>Chris</Name>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
<Phone Type="Home">564-555-0122</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">442-555-0154</Phone>
<Address>
  <Street>124 Kutbay</Street>
  <City>Montara</City>
  <State>CA</State>
  <Zip>94037</Zip>
  <Country>USA</Country>
</Address>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318408/remove-empty-xml-tags

Comment: You might find [this link](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Descendants("Employee")
    .Where(e => e.Descendants().Any(d => String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value)))
    .Remove();
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Comment: BTW `d.IsEmpty` will return `content == null`. `d.Value` in this case simply return `String.Empty` which also will match condition `String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value)`. So, you don't need to use both `d.IsEmpty` and `String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value)`. Also `d.IsEmpty` will return `false` for your empty tags, because they have white spaces.