# Remove empty HTML from a document

Tags: php, regex

I need some help stripping empty tags in my HTML. There is a solution here:

[Remove empty tags using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129738/remove-empty-tags-using-regex)

But I can't use JS, [**and I should never use Regular expressions to parse HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/257493).

I need to clean inputs with PHP, and I also need to get more than just empty tags.

I also need to catch tags like this:

```
<p> </p> (variable whitespace with nothing in the tag)
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><br/><p>
<p><br /></p>
```

What can I do to catch bad markup like that before it makes it to the database (WYSIWYGs)?

Comment: don't use regexes for xml/html.

Comment: Is your input 'valid XHTML' ? If so, an xslt can be a solution for your case.

Comment: How else do you clean input from WYSIWYGs in forms? Multiple str_replace for each case?

Comment: But if you strip those....it wont be WYSIWYG anymore?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It shouldn't enter empty tags like that. It messes up style on elements like p tags that might have margin bottom, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse it with [a document object model parser](http://php.net/domdocument), check the text content of nodes, remove nodes that don't meet your criteria (parses as a script tag, contains whitespace, is an iframe, etc).

Quite a lot of sample code in the comments section as well.

Here's a bunch of code that does something like that (adopted from random cut+paste on php.net)

```
<?php

$sampleHTML = "
<p>  </p>
<p> &nbsp;   <p>
<p><br/></p>
<p><br /></p>
<span>Non-empty span<p id='NestedEmptyElement'></p></span>
";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($sampleHTML);
$domNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagname('*');
$domElemsToRemove = array();
foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) {
  $domElement->normalize();
  if (trim($domElement->textContent, "\xc2\xa0 \n \t ") == "") {
    $domElemsToRemove[] = $domElement;
  }
}

foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){
    try {
      $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      //node was already deleted.
      //There's a better way to do this, it's recursive.
    }
}


$domNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagname('body')->item(0);
$childNodes = $domNodeList->childNodes;

foreach ( $childNodes as $domElement ) {
  echo trim($domElement->C14N());
}

echo "\n\n";
```

Then we run..

```
$ php foo.php -v
<span>Non-empty span</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

That matches your examples and a little more:

```
^<p>\s*(?:(?:&nbsp;|<br\s*/>)\s*)*</p>$
```

But are you looking only for `p` tags? Can there be several per line?

Yet another use of `normal* (special normal*)*` with:

- normal: `\s`,
- special: `(&nbsp;|<br\s*/>)`

(with non capturing groups)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this for about a day and saw a lot of "dont use regex" which I agree with.

I however had huge problems with DOMDocument messing with my html entities. I would carefully filter text so that all TM symbols were converted to HTML entities such as &trade; but it would convert them back to the TM symbol.

I battled with preventing this behavior for some time. There were some hacks mentioned for this. After a day of battling I thought "why should I work so hard to hack it to work? It should just work.." then I wrote this function using simplehtmldom in like 10 minutes:

```
function stripEmptyTags($html){
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($html);
    foreach($dom->find("*") as $e)
        if( trim( str_replace( array(' ','&nbsp;'), "", $e->innertext )) == "" ) 
            $e->outertext = "";
    $dom->load($dom->save());
    return $dom->save();
}
```

Comment: Why  `$dom->load($dom->save());`?