# Regex to remove empty html tags, that contains only empty children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to parse an HTML string and remove all the elements which contain only empty children.

Example:

```
<P ALIGN="left"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="1"><B></B></FONT></P>
```

contains no information and must be replaced with `</br>`

I wrote a regex like this:

```
<\w+\b[^>]*>(<\w+\b[^>]*>\s*</\w*\s*>)*</\w*\s*>
```

but the problem is that it's catching only 2 levels of the three. In the abobe example, the `<p>` element (the outer-most one) is not selected.

Can you help me fix this regex?

Comment: brace yourself for downvotes on regex+HTML question

Comment: The font element has been deprecated since HTML3 so why are you still using it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3129738/612202 You should prefer the answer with more votes.

Comment: this is the point, I want to get rid of it. I have an older database from where I take this info. There are some notes with formatting saved as text and I want to get rid off useless elements and of font elements. I replaced them with spans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex seems to work:

```
/(<(?!\/)[^>]+>)+(<\/[^>]+>)+/
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/dsjAMw1UDI) with your example.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery and parse all children. For each child you have to check if .html() is empty. If yes -> delete the current element (or the parent if you want) with .remove().

Do for each string:

```
var appended = $('.yourparent').append('YOUR HTML STRING');

appended.children().each(function () 
{
    if(this.html() === '')
    {
        this.parent().remove(); 
    }
});
```

This will add the items first and delete, if there are empty children.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
function removeEmtpyElements(str, iterations){
    var re = /<([A-z]+)([^>^/]*)>\s*<\/\1>/gim;
    var subst = '';
    
    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        str = str.replace(re, subst);
    }
    
    return str;
}
```