# How to remove empty html tags (which contain whitespaces and/or their html codes)

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Need a regex for preg_replace.

This question wasn't answered in "another question" because not all tags I want to remove aren't empty.

I have not only to remove empty tags from an HTML structure, but also tags containing line breaks as well as white spaces and/or their html code.

Possible Codes are:

<br /> &nbsp; &thinsp; &ensp; &emsp; &#8201; &#8194; &#8195;

BEFORE removing matching tags:

```
<div> 
  <h1>This is a html structure.</h1> 
  <p>This is not empty.</p> 
  <p></p> 
  <p><br /></p>
  <p> <br /> &;thinsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p> 
  <p> &nbsp; </p> 
</div>
```

AFTER removing matching tags:

```
<div> 
  <h1>This is a html structure.</h1> 
  <p>This is not empty.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to remove empty html tags, that contains only empty children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951292/regex-to-remove-empty-html-tags-that-contains-only-empty-children)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<([^>\s]+)[^>]*>(?:\s*(?:<br \/>|&nbsp;|&thinsp;|&ensp;|&emsp;|&#8201;|&#8194;|&#8195;)\s*)*<\/\1>
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/3)

**Note:** This will also work for empty html tags with attributes.

Comment: Hi, i update your test and fails when added empty spaces inside of  a tag. Here's the link with [error](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/19)  and this other [link](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/20) is with the adjust. You just missed before closing the capture group this  `|&#8195;)\s*|\s*)`

Comment: This is a great answer, but should be updated to [this](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/63) in order to deal with these two cases: `<br>` and `<br/>`

Comment: To exclude tags like iframe, canvas, etc
`preg_replace('~<((?!iframe|canvas)\w+)[^>]*>(?:\s*(?:<br \/>|&nbsp;|&thinsp;|&ensp;|&emsp;|&#8201;|&#8194;|&#8195;)\s*)*<\/\1>~iu', "", $html)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) It uses the following function:

```
function cleaning($string, $tidyConfig = null) {
    $out = array ();
    $config = array (
            'indent' => true,
            'show-body-only' => false,
            'clean' => true,
            'output-xhtml' => true,
            'preserve-entities' => true 
    );
    if ($tidyConfig == null) {
        $tidyConfig = &$config;
    }
    $tidy = new tidy ();
    $out ['full'] = $tidy->repairString ( $string, $tidyConfig, 'UTF8' );
    unset ( $tidy );
    unset ( $tidyConfig );
    $out ['body'] = preg_replace ( "/.*<body[^>]*>|<\/body>.*/si", "", $out ['full'] );
    $out ['style'] = '<style type="text/css">' . preg_replace ( "/.*<style[^>]*>|<\/style>.*/si", "", $out ['full'] ) . '</style>';
    return ($out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) but, try this

```
\<.*\>\s*\&.*sp;\s*\<\/.*\>|\<.*\>\s*\<\s*br\s*\/\>\s*\&.*sp;\s*\<\/.*\>|\<.*\>\s*\&.*sp;\s*\<\s*br\s*\/\>\<\/.*\>
```

Basically matches

- Tags with HTML space elements in them OR
- Tags with breaks occurring before HTML space elements in them
- Tags with breaks occurring after HTML space elements in them