# Remove empty tags with line breaks from HTML

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>Summary: <br>
    <table class="stats data tablesorter marg-bottom">
        <thead><tr><th>Team</th><th>Wins</th><th>Losses</th><th>Ties</th><th>Win %</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Team 1</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>56.21</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Team 2</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>43.79</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


<div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I want this as result:

```
<body>Summary: <br>
    <table class="stats data tablesorter marg-bottom">
        <thead><tr><th>Team</th><th>Wins</th><th>Losses</th><th>Ties</th><th>Win %</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Team 1</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>56.21</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Team 2</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>43.79</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Easiest would be to code it correctly, unfortunately, this comes out of a very very old version of CKEditor and I can't upgrade it (due to other implications).

What `preg_replace` or recursive function or loop can I run to remove the empty `<div>` tags and the unneeded empty lines?

Comment: almost simillar thing has been done, you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865464/how-to-remove-empty-html-tags-wich-containing-whitespaces-and-or-their-html-cod

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Thanks for the input @jww. As you can tell, the question is almost two years old and has already been answered. But thanks again, really insightfull and well thought out comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this HTML in a variable called `$html`:

```
// Replace empty <div> tags with nothing
$html = preg_replace("/<div>\s*<\/div>/", "", $html);

// Replace multiple newlines in a row with a single newline
$html = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $html);

echo $html;
```

**EDIT**

Full working code, including output:

```
<?php

$html = <<<END
<body>Summary: <br>
    <table class="stats data tablesorter marg-bottom">
        <thead><tr><th>Team</th><th>Wins</th><th>Losses</th><th>Ties</th><th>Win %</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Team 1</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>56.21</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Team 2</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>43.79</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


<div>
    </div>
</body>

END;

// Replace empty <div> tags with nothing
$html = preg_replace("/<div>\s*<\/div>/", "", $html);

// Replace multiple newlines in a row with a single newline
$html = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $html);

echo $html;

// OUTPUT:

// <body>Summary: <br>
//     <table class="stats data tablesorter marg-bottom">
//         <thead><tr><th>Team</th><th>Wins</th><th>Losses</th><th>Ties</th><th>Win %</th></tr></thead>
//         <tbody>
//             <tr>
//                 <td>Team 1</td>
//                 <td>95</td>
//                 <td>74</td>
//                 <td>0</td>
//                 <td>56.21</td>
//             </tr>
//             <tr>
//                 <td>Team 2</td>
//                 <td>74</td>
//                 <td>95</td>
//                 <td>0</td>
//                 <td>43.79</td>
//             </tr>
//         </tbody>
//     </table>
// </body>

?>
```

Comment: @Albert See my edit, which uses your exact input and gets the expected output.