# Clean html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a user-submitted data that contains HTML and i am store that data in database. 
Data such as:

```html
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class="myclass">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
```

How i can clean this Html

```html
<div class="myclass">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty tags using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129738/remove-empty-tags-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Question is not really clear on what exactly you are trying to clean, but there's a jQuery function:

```
$(".myclass").html("");
```

This will replace html in selected element to nothing.

Comment: i am receive html data that contain empty tag like class with ""  other tag with no content so i want to remove them and store clean html in database

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
    });
});
```

This jQuery code remove empty `<p></p>`

Comment: how about empty div which the OP also want?

Comment: $('div').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
 });            Try to change 'p' to 'div' or look for class=""

Answer (score 0):

1. Use :empty selector
2. If you have large im not sure if this is a good solution

```js
$("*:empty").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class="myclass">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use js to clean the `parent`

```
function clean(parent){
    var children=parent.children
    var i=0
    while(i<children.length){
      if(children[i].innerHTML==""){
        parent.removeChild(children[i])
        i--;
      }
      i++;
    }
}

var parent=document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0]
clean(parent)
```