# Clean XML from empty elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I'm struggling with problem, what probably has simple code solution, but was not able to find it for Javascript.

I want to clean XML from empty elements using DOMParser or whatever JS tools.

Example input:

```
<xml>
  <test>1</test>
  <test2></test2>
  <test3></test3>
  <test4>
    <blah>1</blah>
    <bruh></bruh>
  </test4>
</xml>
```

Output:

```
<xml>
  <test>1</test>
  <test4>
    <blah>1</blah>
 </test4>
</xml>
```

**Edit:**
First suggestion from [#4800808](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3129760/4800808) were OK for that example, but it does not work, when XML has attributes. What about this:

```
<xml>
  <test>1</test>
  <test2></test2>
  <test3></test3>
  <test4 attr="value">
    <blah>1</blah>
    <bruh></bruh>
  </test4>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the XML stored in a string `x`, call `x.replace(/<[\S]+?><\/[\S]+?>/, "")`.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3129760/4800808

Comment: Thank you, it really works for simple XML, but when i tested it on my complex example, I discovered that it does not process nodes, what contain attributes in parent nodes.